# WebRequest is calling localhost

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I am attempting to call a RESTful API but for some reason, whenever I make the call I seem to be calling localhost instead of the specified URI.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace WebApi.Models
{
    public class GET
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            /* The XML Request */
            string xmlRequest = @"
            <request>        
                <auth>
                    <type>basic</type>
                    <username>USERNAME</username>
                    <password>PASSWORD</password>
                </auth>
                <method>
                    <name>getProperties</name>
                    <params>
                        <propertyIds>356930</propertyIds>
                        <showAllStatus>0</showAllStatus>
                    </params>
                </method>
            </request>";

            /* Initiate a Web Request object */
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("https://ach.entrata.com/api/properties");
            request.Method = "GET";

            /* Initiate the request writer */
            StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());

            /* If you want to send an XML Request, use these options */
            request.ContentType = "APPLICATION/XML; CHARSET=UTF-8";
            requestWriter.Write(xmlRequest);

            requestWriter.Close();

            /* Read the response */
            StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            responseReader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a screenshot of the response:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwI2b.png)

Notice it claims that the requested URL is http://localhost:62324/ and not the URI I specified in my code. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Did you use fiddler to see where the request is going ?When I browsed `https://ach.entrata.com/api/properties` in google chrome it took me to API documentation page `https://ach.entrata.com/api/documentation`. You need to check first if request is really going to the specified url.

Comment: I did not know fiddler was a thing. I'll take a look at that. However, that was the request URL provided to me by the company.

Comment: How did you get that screen shot? Did you try to browse the URL somewhere?

Comment: I pressed F5 in Visual Studio and it ran w/ internet explorer.

Comment: Are you running this code from Console Application or from Web Application? Can you share how exactly your project looks like? I think the error you are seeing is from your local code note from the service URL.

Comment: I think error is on following line :  StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());.  The constructor should be a file name.  So error is occuring because the location of the file is bad.

Comment: This code would not run as it WebRequest will not allow populating request contents for httpmethod GET. It will throw error at line ` StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());`. To me it looks like OP's code is not even reaching this point.

Comment: I believe it is a web application (sorry I am kind of new to this). What can I do to help you out?

Comment: I tried running less and less of the code to see exactly how far it was getting. The same dialog popped up every time. It may not be running even a bit of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I'll paste the fixed code here in case anyone else runs into this problem in the future. The main error was that I was trying to run the code as a web application when it needed to be a console application. Additionally, I was trying to run a GET call but it requires a POST call in order to send the query arguments to the server. After that I had another small error and I fixed it by moving the @" onto the next line to eliminate any leading spaces. Once that was done my code ran fine and returned the information to the console window perfectly.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace Console_API_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /* The XML Request */
            string xmlRequest = 
          @"<request>


            <auth>

                <type> basic </type>

                <username> USERNAME </username>

                <password> PASSWORD </password>

            </auth>

            <method>

                <name> getProperties </name>

                <params>

                     <propertyIds> 356930 </propertyIds>

                    <showAllStatus> 0 </showAllStatus>

                </params>

              </method>

        </request>";


        /* Initiate a Web Request object */
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://ach.entrata.com/api/properties");   
        request.Method = "POST";

        /* Initiate the request writer */
        StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());

        /* If you want to send an XML Request, use these options */
        request.ContentType = "APPLICATION/XML; CHARSET=UTF-8";                             
        requestWriter.Write(xmlRequest);

        requestWriter.Close();

        /* Read the response */
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        responseReader.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(responseData);
    }
}
}
```